# How to remove one facet category from facet_wrap after using tidyr to reshape data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, facet, facet-wrap

I am trying to plot some data and see below the replicable example, starting from the relevant libraries

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)
```

and the creation of the random dataset see below:

```
data <- data.frame(replicate(3, sample(0:100, 100, rep=TRUE)))
data$Place <- sample(c("PlaceA", "PlaceB","PlaceC"), size = nrow(data), prob = c(0.76, 0.14, 0.10), replace = TRUE)
data$Preference <- sample(c("Strong", "Medium","Low"), size = nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
data$Risk <- sample(c("Yes","No"), size = nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
colnames(data) <- c("A","B","C","Place","Preference","Risk")
rownames(data) <- NULL
```

After this step I am trying to get the data along a different shape by using tidyr package

```
data_long <- tidyr::gather(data, key = type_col, value = categories, -c("A","B","C","Place","Preference"))
```

And then I wish to plot the proportions of respondents saying yes to risk by place- see below the code to achieve the visual output

```
data_long %>%
count(type_col, categories,Place) %>%
left_join(data_long %>% count(type_col, Place, name = "m"),by = c("type_col", "Place")) %>%
mutate(Prop = n/m) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = categories, y = Prop, fill = Place)) +
geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Prop)),
            hjust = 0.1, 
            position = position_dodge(1)) +
facet_wrap(~ type_col, scales = "free_x", ncol = 3) +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Oranges") + #scale_x_discrete(limits = positions)+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), labels = scales::percent) +
xlab("") +
ylab("") +
coord_flip() +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12))
```

See below the output which is correct. Yet, I do not want to show the yes and nos, but just the yes proportions. Is there an easy way to just plot the output below while retaining just one option of the facets (Yes in this case)? Thanks for the help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
data_long %>%
  count(type_col, categories,Place) %>%
  left_join(data_long %>% count(type_col, Place, name = "m"),by = c("type_col", "Place")) %>%
  mutate(Prop = n/m) %>%
  filter(categories=='Yes') %>%
  mutate(Place=factor(Place,levels = rev(unique(Place)),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = categories, y = Prop, fill = Place)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Prop)),
            hjust = 0.1, 
            position = position_dodge(1)) +
  facet_wrap(~ type_col, scales = "free_x", ncol = 3) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Oranges",guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) + #scale_x_discrete(limits = positions)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), labels = scales::percent) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That is it! And if I wanted to reorder the percentages to be from the highest to the lowest value, how would I arrange for that?

Comment: @Nicola Just a moment!

Comment: @Nicola I have added an update, hope that helps you!